# Can someone correct me if i'm wrong with this naming rules please?

Tags: java, variables, naming, rules

i have a big test tomorrow and i'm new to java and computer science 
and i have a little blackout and need your help, i will write the naming rules in java according to what i think it is and please correct me if i'm wrong:

**naming classes** = every word will start with uppercase letter and each other word will start with uppercase letter. for instance: TodaysDate, Tester2.

**naming final values** each word will be written with uppercase letters with
'_' sign separate them. for instance : MAX_SPEED,TESTER_2;
**naming instance variables**: every word will start with a lowercase letter and each other word will start with uppercase letter. for instance: maxSpeed,
speed1;

**naming methods**: every word will start with lowercase letter and each other word will start with uppercase letter. for instance: public int getX();

**naming local variables in methods** every word will start with lowercase letter and a '_' sign will separate  each other word. all other words will start with lowercase letters.for instance: int max_speed,tester_1;

i think that's it.
please correct me if i forgot something or wrote a wrong rule.
Thank you !

Comment: That looks good for the most part, local variables inside of methods is largely personal choice, and suffixing them with a number as exampled "tester_1" seems odd and I wouldn't do it.

Comment: Agree that local variables seem off.  I've never seen a Java (note upper case, it's not "java") local variable with a "_".  That might be your instructors preference though so check with them or a class mate.  The rest of your descriptions are right on.

Comment: Just compare it with this: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html

Comment: The convention is, indeed, that there shouldn't be underscore anywhere except constants ("final values" - these should actually be static final values). The rules for classes also apply to interfaces and enums. And remember that packages also have naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather uncommon to use `_` to separate words in local variables, which are lowercase. Usually `_` is reserved for things written in uppercase to clearly separate words e.g. `static final` fields.

There is no right and wrong answer here. You project is free to pick up any [naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming))  but it's important to stick to it. Choosing a well established convention might be desirable, the two most common are [Sun/Oracle Naming Convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html). They are usually well supported by various tools e.g. code formatter in IDE.